# what applicationss x2go session starts?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

When I login on an Ubuntu Mate machine from Windows 8 using x2go, Tilda application is automatically started. When I login with NoMachine, or when I log into Ubuntu directly without network, no application autostarts. How x2go knows which applications to launch at startup?

Comment: My hunch is that it isn't so much X2Go doing something extra as NX failing to start the application as it should. From what I know of Tilda, it is supposed to start with the desktop session, so it is likely being started by your session, not X2Go explicitly. Does Tilda autostart if you log into the server interactively?

Comment: When I log into Ubuntu directly without network, no application autostarts.

Comment: I have both NoMachine and x2go servers. I am not able to reproduce the problem, so it must be something in your x2go configuration. It's not a problem of NoMachine NX. You say that an application is autostarting in x2go even though it's not set physicaly on host. This is wrong behaviour. So Frank who writes "NX failing to start the application" is completely wrong. Rather x2go has been configured to start the app.

Answer (score 0):

When Ubuntu machine starts, a user logs in automatically (strange, without asking password), and no Tilda window appears. But when I logout and then login again (without network), Tilda starts just like as when logging via x2go.
It turned out Tilda is listed in "Startup applications" menu item (System->Preferences->Personal). When removed from the startup applications list, Tilda does not autostarts both when logging in online and offline.